# The difference between Quotient Set and other definition

Tags: abstract-algebra

it a new course and material that I learn, we defined 2 pretty similiar definitions and I didnt understand what is the difference between the definitions.

**Definition 1:** A subset $T\subseteq X$ is called "slice" (dont know how to transkate it correctly) if $\forall x\in X\:\exists! t\in T\colon x\sim t$.

Then we defined the Qutient Set: $X/{\sim}:=\left\{\,\left[x\right]:\:x\in T\,\right\}$

Now an example: 
$$X=\mathbb R^2$$
$$\left(x_1,y_1\right)\sim\left(x_2,y_2\right):\:x_1^2+y_1^2=x_2^2+y_2^2$$

So by our definition the slice is: $T=\left\{\,\left(a,0\right):a\ge 0\,\right\}$
and the quotient set is be like: $\mathbb R^2/{\sim}=\left\{\,\left(r,0\right):r\ge 0\,\right\}$

Does any one understand what did I mean in the "slice ($T$) definition" and can somebody explain me the difference between them both? 
I just copied it as I wrote it in class, and I dont understand the "slice" terminology or definition. Maybe by the definition somebody could translate it correctly?

Comment: @coldnumber rather a *system of representatives* for the equivalence(?) relation $R$. And $[x]\mapsto t$ reminds me of *splitting* maps

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's it. Hagen, so can you explain the relation between the system of representatives for the equivalence and the quotient set ? 
I mean, is there anything more then just the fact that the quitient set is being constructed from the system of representatives of any concrete equivalence (if take any one like that), if you understand what I mean ?
But any way its better if you write what is the relation between them, if my expression isnt good enough in the last strokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that while you wrote $X/{\sim}=\{\,[x]:x\in T\,\}$ you might just as well write $X/{\sim}=\{\,[x]:x\in X\,\}$. The fact that classes are "enumerated" repeatedly this way does note matter, after all you may recall that e.g. $\{1,2,3,2,1,1,4\}=\{1,2,3,4\}$. So, we do not *need* the slice (or system of representatives)  $T$ to define the quotient space.

However, by the definitng property of a slice, we have that the map $T\to X/{\sim}$, $x\mapsto [x]$ is a *bijection*. Therefore we can identify (or at least nicely visualize) $X/{\sim}$ via $T$. And using this bijection as a means of identificatin, we see that - in a way - there is no difference between the two concepts. At least this *may* simplify or support imagination because after all the elements of $T$ are just normal "points" (or whatever the elements of $X$ look like) whereas the elements of $X/{\sim}$ are sets of points.

On the other hand, it is often more elegant (and I prefer) to work with $X/{\sim}$ directly instead of $T$; for example, defining addition on $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ (which is $\mathbb Z$ modulo the equivalence relation $x\sim y\iff n\mid (x-y)$)  requires case distinction if one works with a system of representatives such as $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, but it can be formulated directly when working with the equivalence classes themselves.
Also note, that finding a *nice* slice explicitly may not always be straightforward and is certainly not unique (except in trivial cases).

Comment: Ok, so lets take a simple example, just to make it all sence together: for $n = 5$ $$Z_n=\left\{\left[0\right],\left[1\right],\left[2\right],\left[3\right],\left[4\right]\right\}$$
And here we represented by the method of the slice, as you explaind it as a bijection, and that is a quotient set. We also could write the quotient set as the space of all elements that belong to x~y, that what you ment ? 
But in the congruence relation we prefer the representative method of descreption (i'm talking about the modulo, as you mentioned).